# Ajuda - Como retirar marcação azul Pycharm ao digitar

Tags: pycharm

Galera, boa noite!
Por favor, gostaria de uma ajuda para um iniciante em programação.
Como faço para retirar essa marcação azul no no editor do Pycharm, conforme indicado na foto, para que volte ao normal?

Desde ja obrigado pela ajuda!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta cor azul ocorre quando `selecionamos` uma ou mais linhas de código. Para você, desfazer a seleção (retirar esta cor azul), basta clicar com o botão esquerdo do mouse sobre qualquer lugar da área útil do código.

Comment: @Solkarped Obrigado pela atenção! Mas estou tentando aqui e não estou conseguindo, infelizmente. Tanto esquerdo como direito não estou conseguindo. Poderia se possível, printar sua tela para me ajudar?

Comment: Você está depurando o seu código? Você esta com o debug ativado?

Comment: @Solkarped Estava montando um código e não sei o que eu fiz, apareceu essa seleção em azul. Estou tentando apertar em algum local e não consigo desfazer o mesmo. O que seria debug ativado? Ainda estou no inicio do aprendizado do curso.

Comment: O debug é uma ferramenta de depuração de código. Talvez, você ativou sem perceber. Em todo o caso, salve o seu código, fecha o Pycharm, e depois reinicie-o.

Comment: @Solkarped Infelizmente ainda continua. Sai dele e voltei e continua. Como faço para desativar  o debug? Ate mesmo abri outro arquivo e apareceu essa marcação em azul.

Answer (score -2):

Se você estivesse percorrendo o código enquanto usava o depurador, a linha do ponto de execução atual seria destacada de maneira semelhante (embora uma cor diferente seja usada por padrão):[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]